# Campos com máscara em formulários Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, formulário

Alguém conhece algo que eu possa validar de forma bem dinâmica formulários em Angular?

Tenho um formulário em uma aplicação Angular que criei usando Bootstrap que preciso validar muitos itens, como CEP, CPF, RG, Email etc.

Comment: Mas como assim validar o formulário? No Front-end ou no Back-end?

Comment: Um formulário de cadastro de pessoas por exemplo, onde tenho CPF, RG etc, preciso validar os campos (inputs) do formulário, não deixando o usuário informar RG ou CPF etc inválidos.

Comment: Então pelo que entendi é no front mesmo. Cara existem maneiras diferentes de se fazer isto, com o próprio Angular e suas diretivas(Se vc está utilizando Angular já deveria saber), com o Booststrap e através de propriedades de formulários do HTML5.

Comment: Compreendo o que disse, mas através do npm por exemplo, existe pacotes que você pode incuir no seu projeto para validar formulários, gostaria de encontrar um método bem dinâmico para validar formulários em Angular sem talvez ter que escrever muito código se possível, se você souber de alguma fonte de informações onde há uma maneira bem dinâmica e completa de validar formulários agradeço.

Comment: Não conheço esses pacotes do npm que ajudam na validação de formulários, mas, não acho que ao fazer validações de campos para formulários vc tenha que escrever grande quantidade de código, até pq os frameworks como o próprio Angular vieram exatamente para sanar este problema.